# Spring - checking path variable for null at controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, model-view-controller

I define a path variable at controller Get request using:

```
@PathVariable("ticketId") final Long ticketId
```

How can I check this value is not null ?

Reading https://www.baeldung.com/spring-validate-requestparam-pathvariable `@NotBlank` is utilised but checking for null is not mentioned.

Using:

```
if ticketId == Null {
//return message indicating to user that null has been passed to path
}
```

Seems a bad practice and instead `try/catch` should be used ?

Comment: You can use @NotNull for null Checking

Comment: If(StringUtils.isNotEmpty(ticketId)) should suffice

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the annotation `@NotNull` which validates the passed parameter is not `null`. However, it works only for the object types like `Long`. In case you use a primitive data type `long`, the annotation cannot be used.

```
@PathVariable("ticketId") @NotNull final Long ticketId
```

I rather recommend to use `long` which cannot be `null` by definition.

Alternatively, you can throw [`ResponseStatusException`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/server/ResponseStatusException.html) if there is more advanced logic of validating the incoming parameters. The advantage of this approach is that the HTTP status is propagated to the final response. The following sample results in [`400 Bad Request`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpStatus.html#BAD_REQUEST):

```
if (ticketId == null) {
    throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "ticketId cannot be null");
}
```

Comment: I rather recommend using long which cannot be null by definition. +1

Answer (score 0):

Use @NotBlank for String datatypes and @NotNull for other Wrapper Types but for Primitve types it wont work as they wont return null as they have a default value.